# Beginner Python exercise

Tags: python, loops

I'm having trouble solving problem 2 from this page
[Here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-1/lecture-4-machine-interpretation-of-a-program/MIT6_00SCS11_ps1.pdf)

Here's my code:

```
#Problem set 1 b

out_bal = float(raw_input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: "))
ann_interest = float(raw_input("Enter the annual interest rate as a decimal: "))

min_pmnt = 10
months = 1
prev_bal = out_bal

month_interest = ann_interest / 12.0
updated_bal = prev_bal * (1 + month_interest) - min_pmnt

while out_bal > 0:
        for i in range(1,13):
                out_bal = updated_bal
                prev_bal = out_bal
                months += 1
        if out_bal <= 0:
                break
        else:
            min_pmnt = min_pmnt + 10
            months = 0
            print out_bal

print "RESULT"
print "Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year: $", min_pmnt
print "Number of months needed: ", months
print "Balance: ", round(out_bal, 2)
```

I want to take 1200 and .18 for the first two inputs, respectively. However when I do this the program gets caught in my while loop and keeps printing 1208.00.

When I read the code to myself it seems like it should be working. But I think I'm not using the prev_bal variable correctly.

Also, it's performing the math the way I expect it to the first time it goes through the loop but then it seems like it's not adding 10 to min_pmnt and going through the loop again. It seems like it's just using 10 over and over.

How can I write this so it does actually add 10 and perform the loop again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `updated_bal` isn't changing, yet you are setting `out_bal` to it each time you iterate, and then conditioning the loop on `out_bal` becoming reduced in value.

It looks to me like you are thinking that `updated_bal` changes on each loop iteration, based on its component parts. In order for that to work, you would need to instead use a function that calculates an updated balance each time around.